# Wait for page to load or wait for X seconds before loading player

Tags: javascript, flash, flowplayer

I have a flash player on my webpage that autoplay.The problem is that the video starts playing before other content on the page has loaded.I want make to wait till the webpage has loaded or after a maximum of 2 seconds

```
<object id="flowplayer" width="640" height="360" data="/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":"URL goes here", "plugins": {"controls": {"autoHide" : false} }}' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, I think that disabling the `autoplay` of your flowplayer can be the easiest way to avoid your problem. For the `autoplay` option, take a look [here](https://flowplayer.org/docs/setup.html#player-options).

If you want always use javascript to load your flash content after some time, you can use, as you have already mentioned, the `display:none` like this :

**CSS :**

```
<style>
    #flowplayer {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

And then, for javascript, when the page is loaded :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {    
    document.getElementById('flowplayer').style.display = 'block';      
}, false);
```

Or using Jquery :

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {    
    document.getElementById('flowplayer').style.display = 'block';      
});
```

And using a timeout :

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('flowplayer').style.display = 'block';
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}, 2000);
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: ...Thanks for your help.I want autoplay of video but autoplay should wait for the page to be fully loaded.If page isn't fully loaded after say 2 seconds , start autoplay anyway

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `$( document ).ready()` function  (https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ ) , if it doesn't help - you can insert the flash code with JS/JQuery after a while  with `setTimeout()`, I hope it'll work.

Comment: can you show an example.I can add a style="display:none;" to the object tag.Then i remove it when page has loaded or 2 seconds have elasped.

Comment: I'm not sure that "display-none will prevent the flash to be loaded but you can try. What example do you need?

Comment: then i need to try another approach.What you recommand.I am looking for a JS only approach